# HP E200i Controlller RAID Configuration fon Win2008 Ent, Sql Server, IIS Apps etc need opinion

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, raid5

Actually I run RAID 5 (4 x SAS drives) with

- Win 2008 Ent(1x host)
- Win 2008 End(3x guest)
- Sql Server 2005 Std (on guest)
- 3 x asp.net applications (on guest)
- Hyper-V

I bought 3 x drives to create additional array (on same controller E200i, I am waiting now for confirmation is it possible to have 3 raids in same controller)

I am planning to have 2 x RAID5 (if it is possible)

1. first RAID 5 with all vhd files,
   systems etc
2. second RAID 5 all data files and transaction logs

I am looking for opinion how to optimize data layer (seven drives, one controller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What TomTom said makes sense, although you state that you have 5+3 disks yet you mention 7 disks later - which is it?

Comment: Sorry for mistake :) Actually system runs RAID5 with four drives:
2x http://www.nextag.com/HP-DG146BB976-HP-146GB-634578002/prices-html
2x http://www.globalonetechnology.com/HP_146GB_3G_SAS_10K_2_5_SFF_SP_Hard_Drive_p/dg146abab4_new.htm

The logical size is ~410GB (actually)

I bought additional 3 drives (3x146)
http://h10057.www1.hp.com/ecomcat/hpcatalog/specs/provisioner/99/504062-B21.htm

What is the best practice in migrating from raid 5 to raid 1+0?

Comment: Buy an 8th disk, backup your entire system, see if you can do online migration, it'll show you if you can or not via HP's ORCA interface and/or ACU, if not it's a wipe, reconfigure, restore job.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but it sounds like little sense for me so far. I would go for ONE RAID 10 - and dump it all on there. If you dont bother up the statiic VHD definition and the formatting of the drives (I assume you are aware of the 64k node issue on NTFS) this will give you similar performance.

Comment: Ok I thought about this option too (RAID10)

First, I must check migrating from RAID 5 to RAID 10 with HP controller software. Second The drives I bought (3x) are 15k and the old 4x drives are 10k. Could it be any problem?